# Cython : return a <object>PyObject*, will it leak?

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, cython

I am currently wrapping a library using Cython. For this purpose, I wanted to re-use one function of a pure-C binding.

This is the basic setup:

- mylib.pxd
- old_lib.c
- old_lib.h

In mylib.pxd I do :

```
cdef extern from old_lib.h:
    PyObject* get_pyobject()
```

And then pass `old_lib.c` as a source file in my extension:

```
setup(ext_modules=[Extension("mylib", sources=["mylib.pxd", "old_lib.c"])])
```

In mylib.pxd, I use `get_pyobject` that creates a new object that I want to return like so:

```
cdef PyObject* ptr
ptr = get_pyobject()
return <object>ptr
```

This gives me the desired behaviour, but I am afraid that this will leak the ptr reference.

Will it ? I get confused because I found (old) references saying that you should manage PyObject* references by yourself and call Py_INCREF/DECREF accordingly but it seems that in the Cython [FAQ](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between-pyobject-and-object) they say :

> Note that the lifetime of the object is only bound to its owned references, not to any C pointers that happen to point to it.

Does this mean that whenever the returned value is discarded, the `ptr` will be garbage collected?

In the `old_lib.c` the flow goes like this:

```
PyObject* get_pyobject()
{
     PyTypedObject* typeptr = PyObject_NEW_VAR(MyType, &Type, size)
     fill_attribute(typeptr->attrib)
     return (PyObject*)typeptr
}
```

Where `PyObject_NEW_VAR` is implemented in the python standard library (objimpl.h:196 in my version) using `PyObject_InitVar`. Thus, the returned reference is a *borrowed* reference, but as `PyObject_MALLOC` is used, I guess this is the only reference to this object. Relevant code:

```
#define PyObject_NEW_VAR(type, typeobj, n) \
( (type *) PyObject_InitVar( \
       (PyVarObject *) PyObject_MALLOC(_PyObject_VAR_SIZE((typeobj),(n)) ),\
       (typeobj), (n)) )
```

EDIT :
I have checked, and when using the above code,`sys.getrefcount` returns 3. So as far as I understand, when I create the object, it comes with a refcount of 1. Then, when casting it to `object` its refcount is bumped to 2. It will thus never be garbage collected (unless there is a way to remove two refcounts to an object which has only one accessible pointer) and leak.
If I insert a PY_DECREF, it still works and correctly returns 2. I also took time to rewrite that function directly in Cython, and it returns 2.

Comment: You can look up and print the `ob_refcnt` field of a `PyObject` in Cython. I'd double-check that it's set as you think it should be before coming to any definite conclusions (I think you're wrong about the code not having a memory leak but I'm not sure - have a look at http://tiran.bitbucket.org/python-lcov/Objects/object.c.gcov.html (`PyObject_InitVar` and specifically `_Py_NewReference` which it calls))

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Indeed my objects were leaking. If someone can come up with a nice explanation I'll be glad to accept it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [old documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.2/api/allocating-objects.html) `PyObject_NEW_VAR` is a macro version of the function `PyObject_NewVar` which (as @MadPhysicist says) returns a "new reference" (i.e. has a refcount of 1). I suspect you're no longer encouraged to use the macro so it's disappeared from the more recent documentation.

The fact that it's implemented in terms of something that returns a "borrowed reference" should probably just be regarded as an implementation detail, and not something that means it returns a "borrowed reference" itself.

Regarding Cython behaviour, the cast to `<object>` increments the reference count, and so causes a memory leak. My suggested approach for diagnosing it was to look at the reference count, something like this:

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject # somewhere at the top

def whatever_function():
    cdef PyObject* ptr
    ptr = get_pyobject()
    print ptr.ob_refcnt # prints 1
    ret_val = <object>ptr
    print ptr.ob_refcnt # prints 2,
        # but it will only every be decremented to 1, so never be freed
    return ret_val
```

In terms of fixing it you have two choices - you could decrement the reference count once yourself, or you could change the Cython wrapping of the function

```
cdef extern from old_lib.h:
   object get_pyobject()
```

(don't worry that it doesn't exactly match the header file!).  Cython interprets this as "`get_pyobject()` returns a new reference, so we don't increment it ourself, but handle the reference counting automatically from here."

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for !